# Remove Size data label in a plotly plot

Tags: r, plotly

I have this plot with plotly:
[image: Plot1]

But I want to remove the "size(size): x" data label but keep the names: ["AAAAAAAAA", ......, "IIIIIIIIII"]

This is the code I use:

```
plot_ly(test, x = X, y = Y ,text = Type,mode = "markers+text", size = size)
```

Any tips?

Comment: Please provide some test data, e.g. using `dput(test)`, but try to use only `"text"` as marker.

Comment: Than the circles all become dots with the same radius. I would like to keep the diverences in radius.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest CRAN version of plotly.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, size = round(runif(3, 1, 5)), labels = LETTERS[1:3])

df %>% 
    plot_ly(x = ~x) %>% 
    add_markers(y = ~y, size = ~size) %>% 
    add_text(y = ~y, text = ~labels)
```